# Can I write off equipment purchases for unrelated business

Tags: tax-law

I run a small software consulting company. It is organized as a LLC in California, filing as an S-Corp.

I want to start a second business, but something unrelated to computers. I will need to purchase equipment to start the new venture.

Can I simply make this a new division of my existing company, and write off the equipment purchases as a business expense in the same way I would if I was buying equipment for he existing operation?

If the answer is no, what if they were proximately related? Where is the line drawn typically?

Comment: And your accountant says ... ?

Comment: There is nothing that says a business can't be in two unrelated industries.  Coors, the makers of the world's worst beer also makes Coors-tek ceramics, some of the highest quality refractory materials.  You should be careful in structuring such a venture, but ask your accountant and they can advise you how to do it properly without facing embezzlement charges later in life.

Comment: One accountant told me today that the new venture should somehow do work in the same NAICS code as the existing business. For example the new venture is woodworking, I could produce some sort of online content to go along with it. Still searching for a more complete answer.